# Add new Item to a String Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I got a Basic String Array

```
String[] array = {
        "AAA",
        "BBB",
        "CCC"
    };
```

Now I want to add a new Item to it

```
array[array.length + 1] = "DDD"
```

After I run my application it crashs.

Comment: The array length is fixed after creation. If you need to dynamically add elements try using a list. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

[Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

If you want to change the size dynamically then you should use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

or you could also use a [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)

[Android docs on ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
array[array.length + 1] = "DDD"
```

here assume **array.length is 3** in your case its 3 cause you initialsed in such way so its 3 so when your trying to insert value in it you cant insert value in index which not in its bound so your upper limit index is its **length-1** (cause index starts from 0)

because your trying to acess index which is out of bounds you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception
 thats why your getting crashes in your app hope it clears your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ArrayList instead.

Just write

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

array.add("AAA");
array.add("BBB");
array.add("CCC");
array.add("DDD");
```